# How to change the upload folder in php?

Tags: php

i have this php code for a form with attachment;
i need to change upload folder, with email.
I mean: now, if anyone upload a file it goes to a directory, but i want that this form sends the file to my email adress.

Is this possibile?
Thank You

```
<?php 
// Pear library includes
// You should have the pear lib installed
include_once('Mail.php');
include_once('Mail_Mime/mime.php');

//Settings 
$max_allowed_file_size = 100; // size in KB 
$allowed_extensions = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "bmp");
$upload_folder = './uploads/'; 
$your_email = 'annie.etoile@gmail.com';

$errors ='';

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    $name_of_uploaded_file =  basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);


    $type_of_uploaded_file = substr($name_of_uploaded_file, 
                            strrpos($name_of_uploaded_file, '.') + 1);

    $size_of_uploaded_file = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"]/1024;


    if(empty($_POST['name'])||empty($_POST['email']))
    {
        $errors .= "\n Name and Email are required fields. ";   
    }
    if(IsInjected($visitor_email))
    {
        $errors .= "\n Bad email value!";
    }

    if($size_of_uploaded_file > $max_allowed_file_size ) 
    {
        $errors .= "\n Size of file should be less than $max_allowed_file_size";
    }

    $allowed_ext = false;
    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($allowed_extensions); $i++) 
    { 
        if(strcasecmp($allowed_extensions[$i],$type_of_uploaded_file) == 0)
        {
            $allowed_ext = true;        
        }
    }

    if(!$allowed_ext)
    {
        $errors .= "\n The uploaded file is not supported file type. ".
        " Only the following file types are supported: ".implode(',',$allowed_extensions);
    }


    if(empty($errors))
    {

        $path_of_uploaded_file = $upload_folder . $name_of_uploaded_file;
        $tmp_path = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"];

        if(is_uploaded_file($tmp_path))
        {
            if(!copy($tmp_path,$path_of_uploaded_file))
            {
                $errors .= '\n error while copying the uploaded file';
            }
        }


        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
        $user_message = $_POST['message'];
        $to = $your_email;
        $subject="New form submission";
        $from = $your_email;
        $text = "A user  $name has sent you this message:\n $user_message";

        $message = new Mail_mime(); 
        $message->setTXTBody($text); 
        $message->addAttachment($path_of_uploaded_file);
        $body = $message->get();
        $extraheaders = array("From"=>$from, "Subject"=>$subject,"Reply-To"=>$visitor_email);
        $headers = $message->headers($extraheaders);
        $mail = Mail::factory("mail");
        $mail->send($to, $headers, $body);
        //redirect to 'thank-you page
        header('Location: thank-you.html');
    }
}

function IsInjected($str)
{
  $injections = array('(\n+)',
              '(\r+)',
              '(\t+)',
              '(%0A+)',
              '(%0D+)',
              '(%08+)',
              '(%09+)'
              );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";
  if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
    return true;
  }
  else
    {
    return false;
  }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>File upload form</title>
<!-- define some style elements-->
<style>
label,a, body 
{
    font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size : 12px; 
}

</style>    
<!-- a helper script for vaidating the form-->
<script language="JavaScript" src="scripts/gen_validatorv31.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
</head>

<body>
<?php
if(!empty($errors))
{
    echo nl2br($errors);
}
?>
<form method="POST" name="email_form_with_php" 
action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<p>
<label for='name'>Name: </label><br>
<input type="text" name="name" >
</p>
<p>
<label for='email'>Email: </label><br>
<input type="text" name="email" >
</p>
<p>
<label for='message'>Message:</label> <br>
<textarea name="message"></textarea>
</p>
<p>
<label for='uploaded_file'>Select A File To Upload:</label> <br>
<input type="file" name="uploaded_file">
</p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name='submit'>
</form>
<script language="JavaScript">
// Code for validating the form
// Visit http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml
// for details
var frmvalidator  = new Validator("email_form_with_php");
frmvalidator.addValidation("name","req","Please provide your name"); 
frmvalidator.addValidation("email","req","Please provide your email"); 
frmvalidator.addValidation("email","email","Please enter a valid email address"); 
</script>
<noscript>
<small><a href='http://www.html-form-guide.com/email-form/php-email-form-attachment.html'
>How to attach file to email in PHP</a> article page.</small>
</noscript>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301358/send-attachments-with-php-mail

Comment: what do you want actually..without uploading attachment on server side send mail directly with same attachment??..it is possible to send mail with file attachment without saving in any directory